# unable to include PHP webservice in C#

Tags: php, web-services, c#-4.0

I am trying to add a PHP webservice in my C# application but getting error as below

> The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

The webservice using is from a 3rd party. and the link as below.

```
http://mobile.mycomp.ae/ver_4_0/services/NetworkSearch.php?wsdl
```

Comment: Does the url give any result for you?

Comment: @Chris yes getting result for the url

Comment: Alright so you do have a discovery file/wsdl

Comment: Might be a good idea to take a look [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1149033.aspx?The+HTML+document+does+not+contain+Web+service+discovery+information+#1874477). The answer there might help you out.

Comment: @Chris the result is json result